# Indexing a josnb column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a column in postgresql table with type jsonb.

```
{
    .....
    "type": "car",
     "vehicleIds": [
        "980e3761-935a-4e52-be77-9f9461dec4d1","980e3761-935a-4e52-be77-9f9461dec4d2"
    ]
    .....
}
```

Application runs queries against these fields to fetch records. I need to index this column only for these fields.

How can this be done?

This is query structure with properties as the column name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle f 
WHERE f.properties::text @@ CONCAT('$.vehicleIds[*] >', :vehicleId )= true 
  AND f.properties::text @@ CONCAT('$.type >', :type ) = true
```

Comment: How exactly do your queries look like? In general you could just create a gin index on the whole column. If you use the right operators that index is usable.

Comment: Edited question with query added.

Comment: Hmm, you can't use the `@@` operator with a `text` value. Why are you casting your `jsonb` to `text`?

Comment: This query is in a legacy project which I am working upon and unfortunately don't have much idea of it. During load testing we found issues with this query, hence am exploring if we can create index for this column.

Comment: That query shouldn't even run.

Comment: I would look into query. BTW, can we index on specific fields in json?

Comment: With the `::text` cast the `@@` is a text search operator, not a JSONB operator.

Comment: Try to describe what the query should do.

Answer (score 1):

The query you are using is highly confusing, as it boils down to be a [text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) query, as the `@@` is applied on a `text` value.

I also don't understand the `'$.type > ...` condition. With values like `car` I would expect an equality operator, rather than "greater than". Using `>` together with a UUID also doesn't seem to make sense.

If you want to search for values of type `car` **and** contain a list of IDs, using the "contains" operator `@>` is a better way to do that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle f 
WHERE f.properties @> '{"type": "car", "vehicleIds": ["980e3761-935a-4e52-be77-9f9461dec4d1"]}'
```

The above could make use of a GIN index on the `properties` column:

```
create index on vehicles using gin (properties);
```

If the `type` key is always queried with equality (which I assume), a combined index *might* be more efficient:

```
create index on vehicles using gin ( (properties ->> 'type'), (properties -> 'vehicleIds') );
```

You need to install the [btree_gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) extension in order to create that index.

That index would be a bit smaller but needs a different query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle f 
WHERE f.properties ->> 'type' = 'car' 
  AND f.properties -> 'vehicleIds' @> '["980e3761-935a-4e52-be77-9f9461dec4d1"]'
```

You will need to validate if the indexes are used and which ones is more efficient by looking at the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would experiment with these suggestions.